# Transfer c# code into c++ (Microsoft c++) version

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, atl

I need to translate this code into c++ (microsoft c++ ATL/MFC)project.

```
            var ticks = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            byte[] c = BitConverter.GetBytes(ticks);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[c.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte)c[i];
```

1. What is corresponding call in c++ for System.dateTime.Now.Ticks?
2. What is corresponding Bitconverter in c++.

**Note:** Boost is not an option in this project.

Comment: `std::chrono` if your compiler has it, or [`boost::chrono`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono.html) otherwise.  If you must, use [CTime::GetCurrentTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/weky6tf3(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/166663).

Comment: Why do you get the `byte`s in a new array, and then copy them one by one to a second new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetTickCount() may work as an equivalent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx

It returns a value of 32 bits (DWORD), so the buffer would be of size = 4 bytes.
Regarding bitconverter, you don't need it, since C++ can cast the pointer directly:

```
DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();
BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)&ticks;
```